# remote desktop application with wrongly displayed buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, remote-desktop

I have a winform within a remote desktop application that is built dynamically with a container panel for a toolbar with large (regular) buttons. The application is writen in C# and .NET 4.0. The application is viewed as it should only if I do not maximize the window (meaning restored view is fine).

Now, after RDP login - within most client computers - the application looks fine (even when we maximize and restoring). Within low resolution client computers (800x600), the buttons on the toolbar are not displayed in the right position (such as in the 1024x768 clients).

I used double buffering and it didn't help... the problem may or may not be depended on the screen resolution (it can be memory issue or something). It is not a problem of localization layout.

The following image shows the Fine and Bad states: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPHD9.jpg

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks very off, can you reproduce by running locally (without RDP) using 800x600 resolution? What if you change your monitor DPI settings?

Comment: If I change the resolution or other graphics settings (in a computer that has displayed it right), I cannot reproduce it... It cannot be reproduced also locally... This is bizzare - and it seems I would have to right the toolbar from scratch, though I don't know what I did in order to make it displayed like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so in case anybody gets to this kind of case, this is the thing that made the issue:

In the form, there was an empty repaint override. The programmer that created the form was overriding the repaint with an empty method (don't know why, I guess I'll ask my team for the business logic).

How did I reproduce it in the development environment? Following Albin Sunnanbo's note, I ran the RDP application in minimized version during initialization, and I noticed that it occurs with large resolution clients also in this use case... So, I know repaint occurs while performing a window resize - and this made me suspicious about the method...

==> On a side note, I guess this is why inheritance is so bad, and going on to WPF is better. It took me 3 days to understand why this issue occurred.